# How to globalize the files I'm using

Tags: c++, file, global

I am using several functions that uses the same input and output files, I need to find a way to globalize them so that I could use the functions without declaring them inside the function each time its called
to calirfy

```
void func1()
{
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    infile.open(" input.txt");
    outfile.open("output.txt"); 
    ......}

void func2()
{
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    infile.open(" input.txt");
    outfile.open("output.txt"); 
    ......}
```

I need to only use the declaration files once not each time in each function, how can I do that?

Comment: your question isn't very clear. Is it the files that you wish to globalize? What exactly do you mean by globalize. Do you mean to declare as globally and declare as extern or pass into the functions as pointers perhaps? How are you declaring the files? Are they FILE pointers, filenames or what? Could you provide the code that you have?

Comment: I edited the question for u , check it out

Comment: see the edited answer according to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can put those functions in saperate class. what you will have to do is to create the object of class where ever you want to call the functions. this is calle reusability

Answer (score 0):

Use `namespace` for declaring the files:

```
//files.h
namespace FILES
{
  extern ifstream infile;
  extern ofstream outfile;
}
```

And define those file objects inside a .cpp file

```
//files.cpp
ifstream FILES::infile ("input.txt");
ofstream FILES::outfile ("output.txt");
```

Usage:

```
void func1 ()
{
  //use FILES::infile and FILES::outfile
}
void func2 ()
{
  using namespace FILES;  // to avoid writing FILES:: always
  //use infile and outfile
}
```

Comment: can i just put the decleration in the main instead of a header file

Comment: @Anon, no you cannot. The declaration should be visible to all the functions where you intend to use these files. Put it in a header file containing that `namespace` and add that header file everywhere you are going to use the files.

Comment: i really dont understand what uv done after i edited my question what exactly do i do

Comment: thats not what i want, i want to declare it once somewhere and use it every time without metioning it again in the functions

Comment: @Anon, Then you can refer the answer before my **Edit**. :). It's plain and simple. I will edit it again.

Comment: so I create a new header file and write exactly this 
       'namespace FILES
        {
        extern ifstream infile;
        extern ofstream outfile;
        }'
and in the .cpp file i '#include"files.h"' and each function i use
        'using namespac FILES'
thats it if so then i have a problem because it doesnt work

Comment: @Anon, It should work. what error it gives ? Have you checked your spelling it should be `namespace` (not namespac). Also you should define them in a cpp (either the same file or the different one). And compile them together.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much I have been able to understand the problem but check out the solution. Hope this could help you.

Define the functions in a .cpp/.h file and you can use the function wherever required by writing the following line :

extern void func1();
extern void func2();

if you don't want to go with the namespace thing mentioned above. But the above answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

There are as many as three types of resource that you are duplicating between your two functions: the filenames; the file streams and the contents of the files themselves. The best way to cut down this duplication and share these resources across your functions really depends on what you are doing with the streams.

Regardless, I'm not convinced that you need to globalize your data. It might be best for you to pass anything you think you'll be sharing between the two functions as parameters like so:

```
void func1(ifstream & infile, ofstream & outfile)
{
    ......
}
void func2(ifstream & infile, ofstream & outfile)
{
    ......
}
int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    infile.open(" input.txt");
    outfile.open("output.txt"); 

    func1(infile, outfile);
    func2(infile, outfile);

    return 0;
}
```

Now that your `main` function is taking care of naming, declaring and opening files, the sub-functions can focus on their real tasks. Also, you can call `func1` and `func2` with files other than "input.txt" and "output.txt" without needing to make edits to the functions themselves. Having the objects exist at function scope - instead of globally - also makes it easier to keep track of what is going on because it is more clear what code is working on what data.

(Note that because the lifetime of the streams spans `func1` and `func2`, things that you do to them in one will have an effect in the other. In particular, the seek positions of the streams will persist. This would not be the case if you opened them afresh in each sub-function or passed in copies of the streams by omitting the `&`'s.)